# method get htaccess rewriterule with value http

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to redirect all requests from http://example.com/index.php?page1=json&page2=http://domain.com/dir/uri.php to http://example.com/json/http://domain.com/dir/uri.php

I have tried:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)$                             index.php?page1=$1&page2=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/$                            index.php?page1=$1&page2=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA,L]
```

and my result from index.php with print_r($_GET)

```
Array ( [id] => json/http:/domain.com/dir/uri.php )
```

I expected results:

```
Array ( [page1] => json [page2] => http://domain.com/dir/uri.php )
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+([^/]+)/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^json/ /index.php?page1=%1&page2=%2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

URI with multiple slashes need to captured using `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable.